# Add Profile Picture to each account and stored into database - cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I want to make adding a Profile picture special it to the account and it's saved (store) into database - cloud Firestore as a  special Profile picture  for each account

for example to more explain:

## there are two users use my application and all of them want special Profile picture for they Profile , how can I store this image to each of them in each database account and Display automatically if a user logs in to his Profile

following the code of the Profile java and activity

Profile.Java

```
public class Child_Profile extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView name;
private TextView gender;
private TextView birth;
private TextView bload;
private TextView Text_Dates;
private TextView Text_Time;
private Button Button_record;
private TextView Text_record;
private TextView Text_hospial;
private TextView Text_Plan;
private TextView Text_Satus;
private TextView Text_Price;
private ImageView ImageView_choose_image;
private Button button_choose_image;
private  Uri mUri;
private static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 1;


private StorageReference mStorage;
private DatabaseReference mData;
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.action_sign_out)
        signOut();
    return true;
}

private void signOut() {
    AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Child_Profile.this,User.class));
                    finish();
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_child__profile);

    name = findViewById(R.id.text_view_Namee);
    gender = findViewById(R.id.text_view_Gender);
    birth = findViewById(R.id.text_view_Birth);
    bload = findViewById(R.id.text_view_Blood);
    Text_Dates = findViewById(R.id.Text_Dates);
    Text_Time = findViewById(R.id.Text_Time);
    Text_record = findViewById(R.id.Text_record);
    Text_hospial = findViewById(R.id.Text_hospial);
    Text_Plan = findViewById(R.id.Text_Plan);
    Text_Satus = findViewById(R.id.Text_Satus);
    Button_record = findViewById(R.id.Button_record);
    Text_Price = findViewById(R.id.Text_Price);
    button_choose_image = findViewById(R.id.button_choose_image);
    ImageView_choose_image = findViewById(R.id.ImageView_choose_image);
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("Photo");
    mData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Photo");


    button_choose_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openFileChooser();

        }
    });

    Intent in = getIntent();
    final Bundle b = in.getExtras();
    if (b != null) {

        String n = (String) b.get("id");

        db.collection("Child Profile").document(n).get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        String pName = documentSnapshot.getString("name");
                        String pgender = documentSnapshot.getString("gender");
                        String pbirth = documentSnapshot.getString("birth");
                        String pbload = documentSnapshot.getString("bload");
                        String pDates = documentSnapshot.getString("dates");
                        String pTime = documentSnapshot.getString("time");
                        String pHospital = documentSnapshot.getString("hospital");
                        String pPlan = documentSnapshot.getString("typeOfPlan");
                        String pSatus = documentSnapshot.getString("satus");
                        String pPrice = documentSnapshot.getString("price");


                        name.setText(pName);
                        gender.setText(pgender);
                        birth.setText(pbirth);
                        bload.setText(pbload);
                        Text_Dates.setText(pDates);
                        Text_Time.setText(pTime);
                        Text_hospial.setText(pHospital);
                        Text_Plan.setText(pPlan);
                        Text_Satus.setText(pSatus);
                        Text_Price.setText(pPrice);


                    }
                });

    }


}




private void openFileChooser() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData()!= null) {

        mUri = data.getData();
        Picasso.with(this).load(mUri).into(ImageView_choose_image);



    }
}

public void ImageView_choose_image(View view) {

}
```

Profile.Xml

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView_choose_image"
            android:layout_width="86dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:onClick="ImageView_choose_image"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_choose_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="-110dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="chid Picture" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_Namee"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_Gender"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Gender"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_Birth"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Birth Day"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_Blood"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Blood Type"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:background="@drawable/calendar"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text_Dates"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Dates" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text_Time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-35dp"
            android:text="Time" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/recodbook" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text_Plan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="Plan" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text_Price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="Price" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text_Satus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:text="Satus" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_record"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/record" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text_record"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="your record" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/medical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text_hospial"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="your hospital" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you know that Firebase users have a [photoURL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_profile) property and you can store the pic in [storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files).

Comment: @Jay yes I hear about it that when the user

Comment: @Jay Yes I hear about it, but all what I saw in youtube video that it's show all upload pic, but what I want is that when you choose  picture for your profile it's automatically in database cloud firestore as a special for him, for his profile and when the user login agin I want it to  Display automatically on his profile , and the very important point that: every user has special picture for each account ,,, thank you jay

Comment: That's really what Storage is for. The users photoURL property is a link to the image in Storage. When the user logs in you'll automatically have that link from the user object and can get the image from Storage. It's special just for that user so each use will have their own pic.

Comment: @Jay ok jay can you help me to give me the code Coinciding with my code above

Comment: The code you need is actually outlined specifically in the Firebase Storage getting started guide. That guide shows how to read/write to storage as well as handling the download URL for the user.